# ArrayList of ArrayList. How remove an intem of inside Array?

Tags: java, arraylist

else if occur the case of

ArrayList of Integer ArrayList and I want remove only one index inside the ArrayList?

For Example:

```
           1  ->  [3,1,8,9]
ArrayList  2  ->  [0,2,4,5]
           3  ->  [9,3,4,5,5,9,0]
```

I wish remove the first index of ArrayList 2 that is the zero (0).

If I use

ArrayList.remove(2), it will delete all first position. That is [0,2,4,5]. But I just want to remove the first position. The number 0.

How to proceed?

In this case, my block code is:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < conta.size(); i++)
   {

     listaRepetida2[conta[i]].remove(conta[i+1]);
     listaRepetida2[conta[i]].remove(conta[i+1]);
     /*         
     listaRepetida2.get(conta.get(i)).remove(conta.get(i+1));
     listaRepetida2.get(conta.get(i)).remove(conta.get(i+1));
      */
     i+=2;
    }
```

conta, get the index of listaRepetida[i][j] that will be remove from it.

Comment: Arrays or ArrayLists? They are different things

Answer (score 3):

You get the inner list which is at index 1:

```
List<Integer> innerList = outerList.get(1);
```

And then you remove its first element:

```
innerList.remove(0);
```

Or, in a single instruction:

```
outerList.get(1).remove(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should fetch the array you want to remove elements from. You an simply use onstruct like this:

```
arr.get(2).remove(0);
```

Comment: Indices are zero-based, even though the OP enumerates them 1,2,3...

Answer (score 0):

See it;

My code (don't remove):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RemoveRepetidas
{
  ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> listaRepetida = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

  RemoveRepetidas (ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> _listaRepetida)
  {
    this.listaRepetida = _listaRepetida;    
  }


  String removeRepetida()
  {      
         System.out.println(this.listaRepetida);
         ArrayList<Integer> conta = new ArrayList<Integer>();         
         ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> listaRepetida2 = listaRepetida;


           for (int i = 0; i < listaRepetida2.size(); i++)
           {                 
              for (int j = i+1; j < listaRepetida2.size(); j++)
              {           
                   for (int k = 0; k < listaRepetida2.get(i).size(); k++)
                   {    
                       for (int l = 0; l < listaRepetida2.get(j).size(); l++)
                       {        
                           if (
                                ( listaRepetida2.get(i).get(k) == listaRepetida2.get(j).get(l) && listaRepetida2.get(i).get(k+1) == listaRepetida2.get(j).get(l+1) ) ||
                                ( listaRepetida2.get(i).get(k+1) == listaRepetida2.get(j).get(l) && listaRepetida2.get(i).get(k) == listaRepetida2.get(j).get(l+1) )
                              )
                              {
                                  conta.add(j);
                                  conta.add(l);
                              } 

                              l++;
                       }

                       k++;
                   } 
              }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < conta.size(); i++)
            {
              //This does not remove
              listaRepetida2.get(conta.get(i)).remove(conta.get(i+1));
              listaRepetida2.get(conta.get(i)).remove(conta.get(i+1));
              i+=2;
            }

           String texto = "{";
           texto += "}";

           System.out.println(listaRepetida2);

           return texto;
  }
}
```

Comment: the arrayList Conta, get two index's:

one -> Get index of ArrayList father
two -> Get index of ArrayList Soon to remove